# Java Scanner NextInt not outputting all Integers within Text File

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I'm a relatively new Java programmer with only a few months of experience so do excuse any errors I have made.

I am currently working on a College project for which I am creating a Dijkstra based pathfinder with interactive GUI. In order for me to start work on this part I first wanted to be able to read in a pre-defined Adjacency Matrix representing the undirected weights for the graph itself as opposed to constantly having to input values myself.

For this I decided to use a Scanner and a delimiting pattern to allow me to quickly read from the text file in question. My main goal being to take out each value within the text file and then append it to a 2D Integer Array allowing me to utilise the data efficiently.

My main issue is that the Scanner itself only reads the first 3 integers within the text file, then stops reading and the program terminates. For my delimiter I am using a Space character (" ") which seems to work fine, but I presume it's something to do with the end of the line causing an issue?

```
public static void readMatrixFromFile() throws IOException {

    File file = new File("Matrix.txt"); //Instance of File with parameter of filename in default location.
    Scanner myScan = new Scanner(file);
    myScan.useDelimiter(" ");

    while(myScan.hasNextInt()){ //Checks whether or not there is a next token within the Text file.
        System.out.println(myScan.nextInt()); //Prints out next item within text file, with respect to Delimiter being ignored.
    }

    myScan.close(); //Safely closes Scanner.
}
```

Many Thanks,

- Michael

Comment: Please try to include the code within the question and not by providing the external links.

Comment: How do you expect us to test this out for ourselves, if all you provide is screen dumps?  Please, copy/paste the actual code and data into the question.  As actual code and text, not as an image.  We don't have the patience to retype your work.

Comment: Remove the `useDelimeter` line

Comment: the easiest way is to simply use getLine while scanner hasNextLine and then once you have the line simply split the string around " " and loop through the array returned by split and add each element to your 2D array where each line is a row in your 2d array

Comment: As @Michael said, you'll have to get rid of the `useDelimeter` to read everything.

Comment: I apologise for not embedding code as text, however Michael you are a lifesaver. I just realised that it will step through all items in the file separated by space anyway! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this so your 2D array is based on how many numbers are on the first line. Reading by a single number at a time it will possibly lead to having to use magic numbers in your code. This method simply relies on how many numbers are in the first row.

```
public static void readMatrixFromFile() throws IOException {

    File file = new File("Matrix.txt"); //Instance of File with parameter of filename in default location.
    Scanner myScan = new Scanner(file);
    Double[][] matrix = null;
    int rowNumber = 0;

    while(myScan.hasNextLine()){ //Checks whether or not there is a next token within the Text file.
        String[] rowOfNumbers = myScan.nextLine().split(" ");
        if(matrix == null)
        {
            matrix = new Double[rowOfNumbers.length][rowOfNumbers.length];
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < rowOfNumbers.length; i++)
        {
            if(rowOfNumbers[i].matches("\\d+"))
                matrix[rowNumber][i] = Double.parseDouble(rowOfNumbers[i]);
        }
        rowNumber++;
    }

    myScan.close(); //Safely closes Scanner.
}
```